# htaccess page redirect on parameters condition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I apply different **RewriteRule** in `.htaccess` depending on number of parameters in URL? For example,

1) If the URL has 1 parameter than it should go to products.php

```
 www.domain.com/mobile
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) products.php?parent=$1 [NC,L]
```

2) If it has 2 parameters then it should go to category.php

```
 www.domain.com/mobile/apple
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) category.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [NC,L]
```

3) If it has 3 parameters then it should go to list.php

```
 www.domain.com/mobile/apple/iphone6
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) list.php?parent=$1&child=$2&subchild=$3 [NC,L]
```

I am a newbie in `.htaccess` but as you can see I have learnt to write **RewriteRule** but cannot understand that how can I put all of my above rules in one single .htaccess file because if I put it like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) products.php?parent=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) category.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) list.php?parent=$1&child=$2&subchild=$3 [NC,L]
```

it gets confused and off-course it should be but how can apply these above rules depending on number of parameters? I hope I made my question clear enough.

I meant to say that if it was a programming question than something like this

```
if($countParameters = 1)
{
   //Rule 1
}
else if($countParameters = 2)
{
   //Rule 2
}
else if($countParameters = 3)
{
   //Rule 3
}
```

but its `.htaccess` and I cannot understand how can I apply my rules depending on number of parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes sure, make sure to use anchor `$` in your regex to make sure it doesn't match more than intended.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ products.php?parent=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?parent=$1&child=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ list.php?parent=$1&child=$2&subchild=$3 [QSA,L]
```

- `/?$` allows an optional trailing slash at the end of your URLs
- Note I have used `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: and what that ?$ means?

Comment: $ means "Match end of string", basically you are evaluating all expression, as Regex may be greedy, you assure to check for all the expression

Comment: You could also reverse the order of the rules so that it checks if there are 3 parameters first, 2 second and only one last; just to be doubly safe.

Comment: @CD001: Actually with `$` order doesn't matter but yes with original regex i.e. without `$` order can be reversed

Comment: It is the presence of anchor `$` (end of line) that makes all the difference. Without `$` in place `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)` will match **all the 3 cases** and will rewrite all 3 cases to `products.php?parent=$1`. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: OK Sir ji! I got it. Thanks a lot Anubhava